# Sharepoint 'content type' not available as a column

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, column

I would like to quickly filter by content type (on sharepoint online) in my document library, but I can not find the column 'content type' anywhere.

Comment: have you enabled content types in advanced options?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to classic experience and Edit the view and add the Column Content type

Answer (score 0):

Content Type is an standard column and you should be able to add it to view to perform any filtering. Edit the current view and add the column content type to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Go to library settings > Advanced settings > select "Yes" for the "Allow management of content types?" option.

[image]

Then check if you can find "content type" when you configure filter in the library.